# Percorrer um vetor até determinado número de índices e formar uma lista com os valores

Tags: python-2.7, arraylist

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

Preciso que a cada 5 índices ele forme uma lista com esses elementos.

Ficaria com a seguinte aparência:

```
b = [(10, 10, 10, 10, 10), (20, 20, 20, 20, 20)]
```

Acredito que seja algo simples, mas não estou conseguindo executar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: deixe o código para vermos

Comment: Não possuo código, apenas o vetor indicado a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa, veja funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/KRN2/0).

```
a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
b = []
t =[] # Temporario

i = 1
for numero in a:
  t.append(numero)
  if i == 5:
    i = 0 # Volta a contagem do zero
    b.append(tuple(t))
    t = [] # Limpa
  i += 1 # Incrementa +1

print(b)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! É o que eu preciso.